# Poky: Can't Build genericv8

Tags: linaro

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to build for aarch64 using the meta-linaro layer.

I'm pretty new to openembedded and have been able to build qemu images by following the Yocto Quick Start Guide but now I'm trying to do my own thing and failing. I just want a minimal image just to make sure it can build then I'll add options later but I'm having many different problems. I've tried using different branches including zeus, warrior, rocko, and master and end up with a different problem for each so I'm going to ask for help with warrior here.

**Host Machine:** Windows 10 using CROPS on docker.

**The Error:**

```
ERROR: ExpansionError during parsing /workdir/poky/meta-linaro/meta-ilp32/recipes-overlayed/glibc/glibc_2.26.bb
```

**bblayers.conf:**

```
# changes incompatibly
POKY_BBLAYERS_CONF_VERSION = "2"

BBPATH = "${TOPDIR}"
BBFILES ?= ""

BBLAYERS ?= " \
  /workdir/poky/meta \
  /workdir/poky/meta-poky \
  /workdir/poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
  /workdir/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-python \
  /workdir/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
  /workdir/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-networking \
  /workdir/poky/meta-linaro/meta-ilp32 \
  /workdir/poky/meta-linaro/meta-linaro \
  /workdir/poky/meta-linaro/meta-linaro-toolchain \
  /workdir/poky/meta-linaro/meta-aarch64 \
  "
```

**local.conf:**
For brevity sake, I am using the automated local.conf with these changes:

```
Added: CONNECTIVITY_CHECK_URIS = "https://www.google.com"
Changed: MACHINE ?= "genericarmv8b"
```